# Print Message Inline Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm trying to print a simple hello world string to the console in inline assembly. My assembly (below) works perfectly fine. I tried translating it into GAS as best as possible but putting the variables into the registers through extended assembly proved rather difficult. From what I can tell, the `printmsg` function doesn't actually do/print anything.

Assembly:

```
section .text
   global _start

_start:
    ; Write string to stdout
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, string
    mov edx, strlen
    int 0x80

    ; Exit
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80

section .data
    string  db 'Hello, World!',10
    strlen equ $ -  string
```

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printmsg(char *msg, int len){
    asm(    "movl $4, %eax;"
            "movl $1, %ebx;"
       );
    asm(    "movl %1, %%ecx;"
            "movl %1, %%edx;"
            :
            : "c" (msg), "d" (len)
        );
    asm("int $0x80");
}

int main(){
    char *msg = "Hello, world!";
    int len = strlen(msg);

    printf("Len is %d\n*msg is %s\n", len, msg);

    /* Print msg */
    printmsg(msg, len);

    /* Exit */
    asm(    "movl $1,%eax;"
            "xorl %ebx,%ebx;"
            "int  $0x80"
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Michael's extended assembly example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printmsg(char *string, int length){

    asm(    "int $0x80\n\t"
            :
            :"a"(4), "b"(1), "c"(string), "d"(length)
       );

}

int main(){

    char *string = "Hello, world!\n";
    int variable = strlen(string);

    /* Print msg */
    printmsg(string, variable);

    /* Exit */
    asm(    "movl $1,%eax;"
        "xorl %ebx,%ebx;"
        "int  $0x80"
    );

}
```

Comment: If you aren't taking a course, and want to learn assembly, then I recommend you seriously consider not _starting_ with inline assembly. It adds complexities that may be difficult to understand if you are new. I'd recommend creating your `printmsg` in a separate assembler file, assemble it and link it to your _C_ program.

Comment: `printmsg` should also work with something like: `void printmsg(char *msg, int len){
    __asm__ ("int $0x80\n\t"
            :
            : "a"(4), "b"(1), "c" (msg), "d" (len));
}
`

Comment: If you are using gcc, basic asm (ie asm without parameters) does NOT support changing the contents of registers, flags or memory (which you are still doing with `movl $4, %eax`).  While it will compile and may (seem to) work, depending on this unsupported behavior will eventually result in hard-to-track-down failures.  Better to use extended asm, as Michael proposes above.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Fixed the answer. Do you have a case where the previous example would fault? It seemed like using that in a local function was rather controlled.

Comment: Going back to your original post, consider what would happen if printmsg returned a value (for example: always returns 0). Following the rules for calling functions, the compiler would want to put this value in eax. In unoptimized code it would do this at the end of the function, which would be safe. But in optimized code, it could do this at any point in this function since it "knows" that eax isn't changed by any of the other statements. So suddenly eax contains 0 when calling the interrupt instead of 4.  Just looking at the c code would make it hard to understand why/how that was happening.