# What is the fastest way to print a single char on the Windows console in C?

Tags: c, windows, printf, stdio

I am working on a project using the console and I need printing to be as fast as possible. Even `putc()` is too slow (I checked all the common methods of printing and their run times). After carefully reading the Windows API low-level I/O documentation, I am only more confused; there is barely any code, I find it hard to understand, and I am not sure it will speed up the printing process.

So I was wondering if there is any faster method for printing a single character to the console using Windows (not the API, the os)?

Edit: Is nCurses any faster than just the Windows API or `putc()`?

Comment: Maybe you should be using assembler?

Comment: You can look into embedding assembler into a C program, see here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15971/Using-Inline-Assembly-in-C-C  But this is definitely getting into the "dark magic" realm, so it's probably not something you want to do unless there's no other way.

Comment: Why do you think the C program is the bottleneck rather than the speed with which the terminal/console software can display incoming characters?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil - I don't know which is the bottleneck to be honest since it's not clear what hardware the user is running on, what C compiler, etc.  Inline assembler is just something to try to see if it makes any difference.  It may improve the speed, make no difference, or make it worse, nobody knows until it's tried.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I do not think that, I am just wondering if it can be sped up?

Comment: If you want to try to print something using inline assembler, you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36214696/print-message-inline-assembly

Comment: "I don't know which is the bottleneck" so you're shooting in the dark.

Comment: "Rendering" is often done into a secondary buffer, then the 'primary' and 'secondary' are swapped... The scene would change between two refresh cycles. You'd have to get into the cellar plumbing to address this, I'd suspect.

Comment: "Even putc() is too slow" --> do not print characters 1 at a time.  Use `fwrite()` or some buffer write routine.  The real goal is speed, not artificial sub-goal of "print a single char".

Comment: @RetiredNinja That was a commentator, not the OP.

Comment: Why do I get the feeling the purpose of this project is to simulate the "Matrix" screen with its _dripping_ and fading green 1's and 0's and stuff?

Comment: Haven’t we all been over this before?

Comment: Did you benchmark while redirecting into a file or even "nul"? This does not use any Windows GUI stuff and commonly speeds up things a lot.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I am just trying to make a game engine for the C console where I print values in a matrix where each value represents a pixel. I am using the SetConsoleCursorPosition() to draw at the coordenates of every pixel